# Using the default replica configuration from elasticsearch.yml

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I want to use the settings for the number of replicas specified in the elasticsearch.yml when creating a new index with the ElasticsearchTemplate.
The purpose of this is to set the number of replicas based on the environment in which the ES is running. 
For example: Use 4 replicas in live and 2 in test.

I think this can be achieved by setting the number of replicas to the appropriate value in the elasticsearch.yml in each environment.

But when I create a new index using the ElasticsearchTemplate (e.g. by using the Spring Data ES repositories) the create index request contains the default value 1 from the @Document annotation.

```
@Persistent
@Inherited
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
public @interface Document {

        String indexName();

        String type() default "";

        short shards() default 5;

        short replicas() default 1;

        String refreshInterval() default "1s";

        String indexStoreType() default "fs";
}
```

Because of that the default value from the elasticsearch.yml is not used.
Is there a way to force the usage of the default settings for each enrivonment?

I think one way can be the usage of index templates, but is there another way?

Thanks

Comment: My vote would be for using index templates to set the default replica count. Doing so will also allow you to change the number of replicates for different indexes in the same environment and will be more portable should you change how/where your ES cluster is deployed.

Comment: Ok, I thought there might be another way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which version of spring data elastic search you are using but in 2.1.7 there is a new attributes in `@Document`

```
boolean useServerConfiguration() default false;
```

if you set this to be true, spring data repo will carry no default setting on creating index request.